# Is it possible to debug run a script inside pydev without creating a dedicated project

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

Pydev has awesome Python debugging features - stepping through the code, visual variable inspection...

Creating a python script file is a relatively quick and easy process in contrast with the bureaucracy that involves creating a full-blown pydev project.

Is it possible to skip the step of project creation when I want to debug a single file python script?

If I just start to debug a script, I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Strange, I can't really reproduce the issue on the '@'.

Still, you do need to have at least the interpreter and one project configured... then, if you open an external file you can just use F9 to create a new launch configuration for it / specify that project to run.

Afterwards, if you specified things as http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html suggests, you can just use F11 to debug that run configuration or Ctrl+F11 to rerun it.